# What is e in this equation, and how do I solve it?

Tags: logistic-regression

Apologies for the rudimentary question. I haven't studied math and can't find an answer to this online.

Is the '$e$' in this equation for logistic regression Euler's number? If so, it doesn't matter how I calculate this; I can't get the same result. Could someone walk me through it? If I try to calculate this with a scientific calculator, I get all sorts of wrong answers — possibly because I am not using brackets in the right way. Really, I have done no maths at all!

$$\frac{e^{\color{red}{-2.91}+\color{blue}{6.26}*\color{green}{0.1}}}{1+e^{\color{red}{-2.91}+\color{blue}{6.26}*\color{green}{0.1}}} = 0.0924$$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)

Comment: Yes, it is [Euler's number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)).

Comment: Do you get a different value? I just computed it, using the standard definition of $e$ of course, and got $0.092456771$.

Comment: Worth noting that this not technically an "equation", since it doesn't contain a variable.

Comment: Always worth remembering that there's nothing wrong with "too many" brackets, if you want to make sure it's *written* correctly, e.g. `(e^((-2.91)+(6.26*0.1)))/(1+(e^((-2.91)+(6.26*0.1))))`. Unfortunately, it doesn't help *reading* a formula which has "too few" brackets (i.e. requires knowing precedence rules)

Comment: @imallett: I see no reason to exclude the trivial case of no variables from the term equation, when any other natural number would be allowed.

Comment: @wnoise Not that wikipedia is in any way authorative on the field, but the first sentence of their [page on equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equation) reads "In mathematics, an equation is a statement of an equality containing one or more variables." That meing said, $2x = x+x$ is certainly an equation, and if you reduce it to $0 = 0$, I don't think it should stop being an equation just because all the variables happened to cancel out.

Comment: @Arthur I agree. $2+3=5$ is correct mathematics and correctly called an equation - since it has an equal sign in it saying two expressions are the same. $3=3$ is an equation too. I wish I had the time and the courage to edit the wikipedia page (which seems to have quite a history). Perhaps you do.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you're having a hard time getting the same numeric result for that expression, it might be because you're not entering it correctly on a calculator. To get the correct value, you need to use parentheses in the right places.

Using a computer, or a TI graphing calculator, you would enter the expression this way:

> e^(-2.91+6.26*0.1)/(1+e^(-2.91+6.26*0.1))

If you do that, you should get the right numeric value.

Comment: You can also just paste that expression into the Google search bar.

Answer (score 6):

This is the Euler's constant. It is approximately $2.718281828459$... You can read more on it here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)

Comment: To me, the term ["Euler's constant"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_constant) refers to another constant, $\gamma = 0.57721566\ldots$. I know some people have a different terminology. What we are talking about here, $e=2.7182818\ldots$, is often just called "the number $e$", or the base of the natural exponential (or natural logarithm) function. After learning more about it, one can clarify by writing $e=\exp(1)$ (but this will not help someone who does not know $e$ in advance).

Answer (score 5):

Here $e$ is [Euler's number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)), ($e \approx 2.718$) and that is the correct answer to the equation, so you might need to double check your work. If you don't use enough digits of $e$ (i.e. $e \approx 2.7$ evaluates to $0.09375\dots$), then your answer will be off.

[Wolfram Alpha confirms that](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=exp%5B-2.91+%2B+6.26+*+0.1%5D+%2F+%5B1+%2B+exp%5B-2.91+%2B+6.26+*+0.1%5D%5D):

$$ \frac{e^{-2.91 + 6.26\cdot 0.1}}{1 + e^{-2.91 + 6.26\cdot 0.1}} = 0.0924568 $$

Answer (score 2):

Though the accepted answer certainly gives a good explanation of getting *near* the equation's stated "result", I think it's worth noting some points on rounding and errors here.

First, as this is a site for mathematicians, let's take their point of view; typically, mathematicians use arbitrary* precision in the constants and intermediate values in their equation - think *calculator value*. This is good because it avoids rounding errors. Irrational answers like the answer to this equation can then be given to a reasonable number of **significant figures**, in this case, that's 3 (answer is of the form 0.0###). So what does happen when we evaluate the equation with high precision and round the answer to 3s.f?
$$ \frac{e^{-2.91 + 6.26\cdot 0.1}}{1 + e^{-2.91 + 6.26\cdot 0.1}} \approx 0.0924568 = 0.0925 (3s.f.)$$
Note this **is not** the original 0.092**4** from OP's equation.

Now what's probably happened is that the person writing the question has used a calculator value for e and ended up with this: 0.0924568... to which they've done this: 0.0924<s>568...</s> and that's given the (IMO wrong) "answer" to OP's equation.

But there are a few other approaches to errors and uncertainty that I'd like to highlight before writing the equation off as just plain wrong

**When I say "arbitrary precision", what I really mean is enough sig figs so that changing any of the later values will not affect the rounded calculation result. In this example, that happens with e to 6s.f., and so for e = 2.71828... it makes no difference whether that ... is a 9 or a 0 or anything else, the result will be the same when rounded.*

---

#### Method 1: the Engineer

Nothing is perfect in engineering, the equation as stated may be using a rounded value for e. All numbers in the equation are given to 3s.f. (at least, 1 and 0.1 aren't, but let's pretend they are). So logically a 3s.f. value for e of 2.72 should be used. This gives us the answer 0.0923357... = 0.0923 (3s.f.), also not in agreement.

#### Method 2: the Physicist

A Physicist is an Engineer applying the rules more rigorously. In fact, as a Physicist, you tend to take all numbers in the equation to no more than 1s.f. *greater accuracy* than your answer. And the answer should have no greater accuracy than the least accurate number in your equation - which for us is 1s.f. for either 1 or 0.1. Therefore, the greatest accuracy of any of the numbers in our equation should be no more than 2s.f. in order to get a 1s.f. answer. With that in mind, our equation should have looked like: $$ \frac{e^{-2.9 + 6.3\cdot 0.1}}{1 + e^{-2.9 + 6.3\cdot 0.1}} = (0.0924 \ rounded \ to \ 1s.f.) = 0.09$$ and e can be either 3 or 2.7. Testing both of those
$$f(e=3) = 0.08(1s.f.)$$
$$f(e=2.7) = 0.09(1s.f.)$$

The 1s.f. version of the 0.0924 in the original question is 0.09, so the physicist taking values to 2s.f. would be fine seeing OP's equation if it was written as
$$ \frac{e^{-2.9 + 6.3\cdot 0.10}}{1.0 + e^{-2.9 + 6.3\cdot 0.1}} = 0.09$$

#### Method 3:the Biologist

Finally, biologists like decimal places, and similar to what physicists say about sig figs, a biologist would expect an answer with the same number of dps as the least accurate bit of data in the equation. Well if 1 was measured to 0 dps, then actually, the equation the biologist is looking to confirm is whether $$ \frac{e^{-3 + 6\cdot 0}}{1 + e^{-3 + 6\cdot 0}} = (0.0924 \ to \ 0d.p.) = 0$$
Which is true for e to 0 d.p, or to any precision

---

Now I'll admit that most of that was a bit silly, that's clearly not what was *meant* in the question the OP posed, but I do think it's important to have an appreciation of precision in answers and to see that depending on how you construct the equation you can get many different answers. Also as a caveat, I'm not claiming to speak for all Biologists, Engineers or Physicists, I just put those labels to help illustrate the point.

*NB, [this](http://www.wjec.co.uk/qualifications/science/as-a-level/physics-as-a-level-2009/14349.docx?language_id=1) word document is a good resource for info on uncertainties and errors in physics*